# @BeanParam CDIExtension WebApplication null

Tags: java, annotations, wildfly

With wildfly 8.0.0.Final and an EAR project we keep getting nullpointer exception. By hitting corresponding entry point with `@beanparam` annotation, this happens as many times as we have `@queryparam` or `@pathparam` annotations in the `@beanparam` annotated class. After that the app works fine. Any hints on how to solve this. What is the component that eventually initializes the the CDIExtension's webapplication?

exception:

```
 org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Failed processing arguments of org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceMethod@2991850d
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:103) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:111) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:280) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:221) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension$ParameterBean.later(CDIExtension.java:961) [jersey-servlet-1.13.jar:1.13]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension$ParameterBean.create(CDIExtension.java:977) [jersey-servlet-1.13.jar:1.13]
at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:733) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:789) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:358) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:369) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:72) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:60) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:66) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:90) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:733) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:753) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:61) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:80) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector.construct(CdiConstructorInjector.java:64) [resteasy-cdi-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.FormInjector.inject(FormInjector.java:47) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:88) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
... 34 more
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You should definitely add your exception to this question

Comment: Seems that disabling the CDI by removing the beans.xml (and removing corresponding injections) fixes the issue. Root cause still unknown.